# How to create a CheckBoxTreeItem in JavaFX using FXML

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I am desiging a standalone app in javafx (FXML with scenebuilder 8), now I need to create a CheckBoxTreeItem (look at below image) in FXML.

[CheckBoxTreeItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjajM.png)

While searching for it I got a link "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/library-panel.htm" which help me to import a customized CheckBoxTreeItem java file into scene builder but after importing JAR analysis report in scene builder throws an error message "not a node".

Can someone help me to resolve this issue or is there anyother way to create a CheckBoxTreeItem in FXML.

below the customized CheckBoxTreeItem  code :

```
package Action;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboboxTree extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem =
            new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Total list");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);

        final TreeView tree = new TreeView(rootItem);
        tree.setEditable(true);

        tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem =
                new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("List " + (i+1));
                    rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);
        }

        tree.setRoot(rootItem);
        tree.setShowRoot(true);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In a way, it doesn't really make any sense to do what you're asking. The purpose of FXML is to define the layout (i.e. the view) for your application. `CheckBoxTreeItem`s and `TreeItem`s in general are not part of the layout; they are part of the data that is displayed in the application (i.e. part of the model).

Having said that, FXML is just a way to instantiate objects and link them together, so there's no reason you can't use FXML to do this. Here is the equivalent of the Java you posted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <TreeView editable="true">
        <root>
            <CheckBoxTreeItem value="Total list" expanded="true">
                <children>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 1"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 2"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 3"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 4"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 5"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 6"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 7"/>
                    <CheckBoxTreeItem value="List 8"/>
                </children>
            </CheckBoxTreeItem>
        </root>
        <cellFactory>
            <CheckBoxTreeCell fx:factory="forTreeView"/>
        </cellFactory>
    </TreeView>
</HBox>
```

which you can test with

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TreeWithCheckBoxItems.fxml")), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I strongly doubt you can use this FXML with Scene Builder, since Scene Builder is a tool for designing the layout, not a tool for manipulating the data content of your application.

Comment: Thank you James,

Yes you are right, Scene Builder is a tool for designing the layout and I have created a separate java file (controller.java) to manipulate data content.